# How to install EF Core into VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to utilize EntityFrameworkCore in VS Code?  I've looked around for info on this and it seems that just about every example and tutorial assumes Visual Studio 20xx.
Also I don't see Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore in the Marketplace extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc?view=aspnetcore-2.0

you need to install:

.NET Core SDK 2.0 or later
Visual Studio Code
C# for Visual Studio Code

Comment: Okay that should do it.  I was avoiding ASPNet because I'm trying to build a DotNetCore console app and didn't want that extra baggage but the article seems like it'll do me some good.  Thanks!

Comment: Here's a tutorial without ASP.NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite